# ChartJS and Laravel5

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I have the following code in PHP controller:

```
public function getMainAdminBackend(){
    $user_info = \DB::table('users')
                 ->select('role_id', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('role_id')
                 ->get();
    return view('admin.main')->with('userInfo',$user_info);
}
```

In the view I have this chart.js:

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'Jan' => array(33),
        'Feb' => array(32),
        'Mar' => array(12)
    );
?>

{!! app()->chartbar->render("BarChart", $data) !!}
```

How can I convert the array of controller with the format required to JS Chart ?

**EDIT**

Now I receive the following format , the graphic show the number 1,2,3 but cant't print the lines of the graphics.

```
array(3) { [1]=> int(35) [2]=> int(20) [3]=> int(35) }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you call `return view('admin.main')->with('userInfo',$user_info);`

`with('userInfo',$user_info)` sets a `$userInfo` variable in your view with the content of $user_info, so just something like that should do the trick

```
{!! app()->chartbar->render("BarChart", $userInfo) !!}
```

EDIT: i assumed $user_info was already in the correct format but you couldn't figure out how to display it. Reading your comments i better understand your needs.
I don't know which data format chartJS and what you want to display. Looking $data example and your DB query, i assume you want to display data in the format "role_id" => count(*)
so, in that case, i would do something like

```
$userArray = array();
foreach($user_info as $row) {
    $userArray[$row->role_id] = $row->total;
}
return view('admin.main')->with('userInfo',$userArray);
```

Comment: Yes , I use this before , the graphics don't show anything :/

Comment: See the edit, i didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: I edit the question , the format I receive is in the edit @gbalduzzi

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to put the data in the right format:

```
public function getMainAdminBackend() {
    $user_info = \DB::table('users')
                    ->select('role_id', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->groupBy('role_id')
                    ->get();

    $data = [];

    if ($user_info) {
        foreach ($user_info as $month => $value) {
            $data[date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, 0))] = [$value];
        }
    }

    return view('admin.main')->with('userInfo', $data);
}
```